# Show that two presentations are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

It is known that if there is a non-abelian group of order $pq$, then it must be the case that $q\mid p-1$ and this group is isomorphic to $\langle a,b:a^p=b^q=1,ab=ba^u\rangle $ wherein $u$ is of order $q$ mod $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}^*$.

The book I am reading states that

1. this group is unique upto isomorphism, that it is independent of the choice of $u$, and
2. every element is distinctly written as $a^xb^y$ where $0\leq a< p$ and $0\leq b<q$.

But if $p=3$, $q=7$ and $u=2$, $ba^2b$ can be expressed as $baab=baba^2=b^2a^4$ but cannot be expressed in the form $a^ib^j$. I just want to confirm that $2$ is the false claim. Also essentially for $1$, I need to show that it doesn't matter if $u=2$ or $u=4$. I would appreciate if I can get the idea. Thank you!!

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun It is from James G., Liebeck M. W. - Representations and Characters of Groups (2001) page 289

Comment: I think it is written as $b^xa^y$ distinctly but not necessarily as $a^xb^y$. Part 1 is the one I am really struggling though.

Comment: It was a wrong example, I think, because obviously $ba^2b=ab^2$

Comment: 2 is not false, every element can indeed by written uniquely in the form $a^xb^y$ as described in 2. It can also be written uniquely in an alternate form, namely $b^v a^w$ (where $0 \le w < p$ and $0 \le b < q$). This is not a contradiction.

Comment: I think I figured out 2 by showing that there are $pq$ elements and $a^xb^y$ are all distinct. But I'm still struggling with 1